# How do I remove this library error in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

So, I am using a Raspberry pi and Arduino Uno, interfacing them via serial communication.
I am receiving Serial data to Rpi via python library pySerial.
I have successfully received general I/O data like switching action of LED.

Now I am interfacing a MPU9250 (9 axis compass) which works on I2C and SPI protocols, I downloaded the zip library from [github](https://github.com/bolderflight/MPU9250).

I know I can directly operate the sensor with pi via I2C communication, but I wanted to give it a try by completely using Arduino IDE.
the code which I uploaded to the board is this:

```
/*
Basic_I2C.ino
Brian R Taylor
brian.taylor@bolderflight.com
Copyright (c) 2017 Bolder Flight Systems
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software 
and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, 
including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, 
sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is 
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or 
substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING 
BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND 
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, 
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

#include "MPU9250.h"

// an MPU9250 object with the MPU-9250 sensor on I2C bus 0 with address 0x68
MPU9250 IMU(Wire,0x68);
int status;

void setup() {
  // serial to display data
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial) {}

  // start communication with IMU 
  status = IMU.begin();
  if (status < 0) {
    Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
    Serial.println("Check IMU wiring or try cycling power");
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    while(1) {}
  }
}

void loop() {
  // read the sensor
  IMU.readSensor();
  // display the data
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelX_mss(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelY_mss(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getAccelZ_mss(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroX_rads(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroY_rads(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getGyroZ_rads(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagX_uT(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagY_uT(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IMU.getMagZ_uT(),6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(IMU.getTemperature_C(),6);
  delay(100);
}
```

Here, I get successful import message of the library, but when I compile the code, I get this error:

```
MPU9250.h:28:36: fatal error: Wire.h: No such file or directory
```

Even though the file exists in zip file and its within the library I am facing this issue. Can anyone help me with this? your help will be highly appreciated.
Let me know if you face any issues with any of the clarifications I gave.
Also I have succesfully compiled library in my windows and getting the results properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a very outdated version of the Arduino IDE on your Raspberry Pi. Most likely this is because you used `apt-get` to install the Arduino IDE. You should never use a package manager to install the Arduino IDE because this will result in you getting an outdated and/or modified version of the software. You should always install the official Arduino IDE downloaded from:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

For the Raspberry Pi, you will want the "Linux ARM" download.

---

If for some reason you're absolutely set on using such an old IDE version, you will need to add `#include` directives to the sketch for all external dependencies of the libraries. In this case:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
```

In the years since the IDE version you're using was released, dependency resolution has been improved so that this is no longer necessary. So most modern Arduino sketches don't bother with these unnecessary `#include` directives.

---

If you're curious about why the package managers have IDE versions that are years out of date:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2703

Comment: *"You should never use a package manager to install the Arduino IDE"* That statement is very wrong. Your packagemanager takes for of all the dependecies and other stuff, so don't run it down.

Comment: @hellow it's your prerogative to use software that's 4.5 years out of date. The problem is then you'll come asking the Arduino community to help you make modern code work with an outdated IDE and toolchain or deal with bugs that were already fixed. All because you're too stubborn to simply download the IDE. Package managers work great when the package is properly maintained but in this particular case it simply can't be. So we need to adapt rather than being pigheaded.